# Exception management in an ASP.NET MVC Application using Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, enterprise-library

I need some information about best practices in exception management. Not how to code it, there is plenty of information about that, but more like what to do with it in different layers (we have MVC application in .NET), what to wrap and so on.

Just theoretical information. We want use Enterprise library.

### EDIT

Thanks for your answers, but I'm looking more for architectural information. I have read lots of articles on web, like this one on codeproject, some on msdn and lots of more, but mostly they are solving this problem on coding level :(

I'm sure I will use enterprise library, but I have to figure out the scenario (i hope i said id right)
This one was quite useful

[image]

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question...

Comment: `I'm looking more for architectural information` huh? Exception handling should not be planned like that. Catch exceptions that you can handle and leave all others alone. Very simple.

Comment: This architectural scheme is an interesting idea, but IMO it has two disadvantages: 1. It'll hit performance - can a single exception cause two more exceptions to be thrown and three log messages? 2. It's complex. I strongly believe that simpler is better.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use error logging in the "Application_Error" in global.asax. This lets you catch any exception that occurs in your web app. I also use try-catch when taking input from unreliable sources (e.g db access).

I remember this being a wonderful read:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx

A little bit about my prod scenario:
We have IIS servers going up and down dynamically in order to suite system load and save expenses. I log the errors to a dedicated db, since I can't get logs from a server that has gone down. Collecting logs from several servers is also quite uncomfortable. I log e.ToString(), as it saves both the message and the stack trace. One other neat trick: I perform an md5 hash over e.ToString() and save it in a separate column in the errors table. If this hash already exists I increment a counter. I.e. I group errors to enable me to learn about frequency with ease. This also lets you redirect the user to an error page of your choice after logging. I do this:

```
Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.html?e=" + errorHash);
```

In the html file I display the error's hash from the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

I've written several blog entries about exception handling. You can find them here: http://blog.gauffin.org/tag/exceptions/

What I'm basically saying is:

> Do NOT catch that exception!

It's quite important to understand that in most cases you should not catch exceptions unless you really can handle them (or at the top layer).

As for ASP.NET MVC, I've written about the proper way to handle errors here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

If you want an application wide error logging facility I would direct you to review [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Basically it is an unobtrusive IIS plugin that provides exception handling for your applications. It also provides many ways to view those exceptions.

If instead you would like a general purpose logging framework that can be used for both exception reporting along with application logging take a look at log4net.

That aside, the real question is what do you **need** to log when an exception occurs. For starters I would log all of the information necessary to reproduce the course of events leading to an error.

Each application / company is different so talk to you team, co-workers and discuss what else you need on top of this basic rule.

Answer (score -1):

Could create custom exception class per dll or even per class. For each custom exception thrown, create a custom Id to go along with the description this is for tracking and it's for controlling messages shown to users. The ID or range of IDs, determine what friendly message to show to the users. In this fashion you can determine exceptions thrown that where caught and handled, exceptions not caught and handled, custom exceptions, and also track, categorize, and find the code throwing the exception and so much more. To add logging into the mix you could use log4net or common.logging (works with Entlib). This makes logging easy because it's simple to use and implement and there is built in functionality for logging exceptions with all useful information and it can be used application wide.

ADDED:
I think I might have got the Base Exception Class wrong and you will notice that the DebugFormat and ErrorFormat, this is our modified log4net code, however I think that you get the point.

```
namespace Playing.Service
{
    public class UserService
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UserService));

        public void SaveUser(string username, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            try
            {
                Playing.Repository.UserRepository repository = new Repository.UserRepository();

                repository.SaveUser(username, firstName, lastName);

                log.DebugFormat("Saved User Info");
            }
            catch (Repository.RepositoryException rex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Repository Could Not Save User Information: {0}\n Error Message: {1}\nStack Trace: {2}", rex.Message, rex, rex.StackTrace);
                throw new ServiceException(rex.Message, 2400);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Could Not Save User Information: {0}\n Error Message: {1}\nStack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex, ex.StackTrace);
                throw new ServiceException(ex.Message, 12400);
            }
        }
    }


    public class ServiceException : Playing.Common.BaseException
    {
        public ServiceException(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}
        public ServiceException(string errorMessage, int errorID) : base(errorMessage, errorID) {}
        public ServiceException(string errorMessage, params string[] args) : base(errorMessage, args) { }
    }
}

namespace Playing.Repository
{
    public class UserRepository
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UserRepository));

        public void SaveUser(string username, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            try
            {

                //Save data in Database
                log.DebugFormat("Saved User Info Into Databse");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("Could Not Save User Information: {0}\n Error Message: {1}\nStack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex, ex.StackTrace);
                throw new RepositoryException(ex.Message, 3400);
            }
        }
    }


    public class RepositoryException : Playing.Common.BaseException
    {
        public RepositoryException(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}
        public RepositoryException(string errorMessage, int errorID) : base(errorMessage, errorID) {}
        public RepositoryException(string errorMessage, params string[] args) : base(errorMessage, args)  {}
    }
}

namespace Playing.Common
{
    public class BaseException : Exception
    {
        public BaseException(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) {}

        public BaseException(string errorMessage, int errorID) : base(errorMessage) 
        { 
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

            error.Append("(");
            error.Append(errorID);
            error.Append("): ");
            error.Append(errorMessage);

            errorMessage = error.ToString();
        }

        public BaseException(string errorMessage, params string[] args) : base(errorMessage) 
        {
            errorMessage = string.Format(errorMessage, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually _used_ this scheme for troubleshooting real problems in production? It seems complex and error-prone.

Comment: Yes, The text makes it sound hard and complex, however all your doing is creating your own exceptions. By making your own exceptions you can add whatever information that is most useful to you, like an Error ID and/or Message ID, with a name and namespace that is unique to the conetxt. You can then catch your own and generic exceptions and then handle them differently. Your going to catch, log and re-throw an exception anyway, why not throw your own in a way that's more useful. The need for this become more clear when with hundreds of code files across teams and when you have IOC implemented.

Comment: Actually, catch, log and rethrow is a horrible idea. Let the exceptions propagate to the top before logging and you'll get a much cleaner exception trace.

Comment: -1: even worse. You don't pass the caught exception as the InnerException when you throw a new one. Very bad.

Comment: Actually in the code I added above, this allows for excellent tracing back to the source. Especially if you let log4net store this data into a Database. You could add thread ID or Session ID to help tie it all back together. Just a robust environment to work with.

Comment: You clearly don't understand .NET exceptions if you don't get why you need to pass the exception you caught as InnerException.

Comment: Well for one it's an example, you can make it do whatever you want and 2, the log.ErrorFormat lines gets all the exception information and puts it into the log and 3 because the log variable knows the exact class the exception occured in and the exact line of code that cuased the exception, I can then use the log to find the problem. My presentation code only has to deal with controlled custom exceptions coming from the Service layer, not the Inner Exception information that was already stored. The presentation layer should not deal with exception information of say the Repository layer.

Comment: Examples get copied by those who don't know better. The -1 is a hint to them that this is a _bad_ example.

Comment: So are you saying that all errors should bubble up to the presentation layer and make the presentation layer responsible for all the exceptions thrown from the layers below and break the single responsibility principle? Wouldn’t it be better to let each layer be responsible for its on exceptions and then return to the next layer only a few select and controlled exceptions, reducing hundreds of possible exceptions down to just a few key exceptions and keep each layer independent? Isn’t the goal of n-tier development to be able to completely replace a layer and not affect the other layers?

Comment: All _exceptions_ should propagate to where they can be _handled_. Handling includes logging - how do you know what logging technique the presentation layer wants to use? And also, if you throw a new exception, include the original: `throw new Exception2("new message", ex);` Most code should have no responsibility for catching exceptions because most exceptions should not be caught. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8267188/76337

Comment: See now it becomes more clear to me what we are really talking about. I would rather have loose coupling where each layer and dll takes care of itself and can used by other apps easily and you would rather have strong coupling. Both are perfectly fine approaches. However exception and logging design patterns are very different between strong and loose coupling. To me n-tier apps should be a bunch of independant groups of code that take care of themselves and can be grouped together per design. So if 1 app has 4 layers and the other has 6, I can still use the code without a lot of refactoring.

Comment: I wish I had a reference for you. This has nothing to do with coupling. The correct exception handling pattern has _no_ coupling between the code that throws the exception and the code that eventually handles it, unless that code is catching a _specific_ exception. Please try reading [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for link, it really helped me get some my Microsoft Terminology straight, however the text really only explains your average small to medium size applications, not Large Enterprise Level applications, with many databases on my different platforms, many Cache systems, Multiple internal and external Web sites, Lots of windows applications and services, internal and externel web services both consumed and provided, spread accross a WAN, with an untold amount code in who knows how many different languages, etc ... Please read: http://www.infoq.com/articles/error-handling-soa-design

Comment: the design guidelines are the same ones used to design the .NET Framework. Fairly "enterprise-level".